# Code in Django works locally, but not on Digital Ocean server

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.
My program is working correctly on the localhost, but when I run it on my Digital Ocean server, I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'tree' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have no idea what is going on. Let me post some of my code:

The error is coming from the {% url 'tree' %} part of **uploaded.html**:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'tree' %}">Tree</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'ge' %}">GE</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'unit' %}">Unit Req</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'save' %}">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'prnt' %}">Print</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'email' %}">E-mail</a></li>
```

**views.py** under the uploader folder:

```
def tree(request):
   return render_to_response('tree.html')
```

**urls.py** under the uploader folder:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('uploader.views',
   url(r'^$', form, name='form'),
   url(r'^tree', tree, name='tree'),
   url(r'^ge', ge, name='ge'),
   url(r'^unit', unit, name='unit'),
   url(r'^save', save, name='save'),
   url(r'^print', prnt, name='prnt'),
   url(r'^email', email, name='email'),
)
```

If you want to see any other parts of my code, please do let me know.
Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:** On my local machine, it's Python version 3.4 and Django version 1.7.5.
On the server, it's Python version 3.4 and Django version 1.7.6.
Here's the file structure as well:

```
eadvisor
    eadvisor
        urls.py
        settings.py
        views.py
    uploader 
        templates
            uploaded.html
            tree.html
        views.py
        urls.py
        forms.py
        models.py
```

Here's the **urls.py** under the eadvisor folder:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include('uploader.urls'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**SOLVED:** The problem was with my server. It wasn't updating my changes.

Comment: Some related code and the detailed error log, please.

Comment: Complete your question by providing the error.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed the enter button without completing the question. The question is complete now.

Comment: How is [ROOT_URLCONF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) configured on your server?

Comment: @aumo - It looks like this on my server: `ROOT_URLCONF = 'eadvisor.urls'` eadvisor is the name of my project.

Comment: @SarahLee what is your Django Version and Python Version for both Server and Local machines? And Sarah, could you please share the structure of your project directories. (either via github or update in your question)

Comment: @yeo - The question has been updated with the Django and Python versions, as well as the file structure.

Comment: @SarahLee I believed you use a namespace for your uploader urls. please share your `eadvisor/urls.py`. :)

Comment: @Yeo - I just added my `eadvisor/urls.py` to the question.

Comment: This is strange. Namespace isn't the issue here. It works locally, but not on server. How is your django being served in the server? (As in do you use Apache or Gunicorn or DjangoServer?)

Comment: And additionally; do you also get the error when you serve django in the same way on the server as you do locally (e.g. using `manage.py runserver`)?

Comment: @Joost - I only get this error on the server. I get no errors when I do it locally.

Comment: @Yeo - It's being run on the Django test server.

Comment: @SarahLee Sorry, I couldn't solve your problem. The code seems fine. As the last resort is to debug the hardway. If I were you, I will try debugging using `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` and `django.core.urlresolvers.resolve` to make sure everything works even in django shell. If that works, then I go to the next level of debugging using breakpoint to find the bug along the way. And you have to do it yourself, using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. In this process, you will have to figure out why `0 pattern(s) tried: []` when you `reverse` the urls. Hope it could helps. :'(

Comment: @SarahLee that's not what I was asking, but you answered my question with your next reply to Yeo ;-)

Comment: the `0 pattern(s) tried: []` in the exception means that your urls.py don't get picked up, at all. Make sure you run the server from the top-level of the project, and that the python path includes this directory (try `python -m site`).